# How can I run Maven GAE projects in Eclipse?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2

I'm making project with Maven GAE plugin (http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/examples/index.html), but I didn't understand how I can run these projects on local development server. Can someone tell me what I have to do to run my application in eclipse? And I would also like to know how to deploy my application to GAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this myself. I had to add new run option for Maven. Select project and with right click you get menu and there select Run as / Run configurations / Maven / Create new and then add your goal to line goals. Then run it and server should start.

List of goals:

http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-use-google-plugin-for-eclipse.html

Comment: Keep looking for an elegant way of adding GAE default run option into my mavenized gae project inside Eclipse for hours, the Order and Export trick in the attached link really helps, thanks:D

Comment: Note that by following the instruction in the attached link, you can run your mavenized gae project directly i.e. `Run As - Web Application` just like the regular gae project, no need to use maven specific goals to run i.e. `Run As - Maven XXX`.