# How do I make Eclipse and mvn appengine:devserver talk to each other?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I am in the process of switching from [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) to the official Google [App Engine Maven Plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven).
The last thing, I hope, that I cannot figure out is how to get a good debug workflow set up. When I was using GPE, I just set breakpoints and the debugger stopped there automagically, but when I run the dev server via `mvn appengine:devserver`, I don't think the dev server and eclipse are aware of each other.

How do I make them talk to each other?

Comment: http://it-worx.blogspot.com/2010/03/debug-maven-project-in-eclipse.html

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915341/appengine-maven-plugin-configuration-options-like-jvm-flags?lq=1, which has a response from the plugin developer @ Google.

Comment: Note that by following the link [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214958/how-can-i-run-maven-gae-projects-in-eclipse/7215058#comment19702253_7215058), you can configure your mavenized gae project to use the native GPE run/debug options to run/debug the project i.e. `Debug As - Web Application`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I roughly follow the steps @ [developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform) in favor of my previous method.

Answer (score 46):

The first option is to set up your project to use WTP as documented @ https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform. This is the method I switched to.

The second option is to use two debug configurations.

The first debug configuration will run your maven target, namely `appengine:devserver`.
[image]

The second is a `Remote Java Application` configuration, and will connect the debug client to the devserver jvm.
[image]

This also requires some jvm args to be passed to the maven goal.

```
<!-- GAE plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <jvmFlags>
            <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
            <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=y
            </jvmFlag>
        </jvmFlags>
        <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once those 3 things are in place, run the maven debug configuration, then run the debug client configuration, then exercise your application.

There is no support for hotswap yet, so if you change any non-resource files(any java source), the devserver will not see them. Resource files will get deployed(static files: html, js).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that (and pushing for the plugin update). What do the "wait" and "disableUpdateCheck" serve for?

Comment: disableupdatecheck stops the plugin from asking google if there is a new version of the sdk. wait doesn't do anything.

Comment: you need to be using the snapshot version of the plugin for this to work.

Comment: Hi. This approach works but it is somewhat cumbersome as you have to start to launch configs from within eclipse. Also when changing something in the server code you won't be warned to restart the server. Isn't there a way to simply start the mvn appengine:devserver goal in debug mode?

Comment: Also when using the two launch configs approach... the mvn launch configs starts two jvms where only one is terminated when i kill the running appengine so i always have a stale java process running.

Comment: I've stopped using this method, and have created WTP projects. I roughly followed the steps @ https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform

Answer (score 1):

You should be executing **mvn** from **eclipse** in **debug mode**.

[image]

In Eclipse you can configure such maven build commands from eclipse top toolbar **"Run" -> "Debug Configuration" -> "Maven Build"**

Once in maven is launched in eclipse debug mode you should be able to hit the breakpoints.

**Edit** -
One other option is to set up Remote Debug i.e **"Run" -> "Debug Configuration" -> "Remote Java Application"** and listen remote debug port i.e You should ensure appengine:devserver launches with remote debug port arguments - Reference - [Remote Debugging in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346018/remote-debugging-in-eclipse)

Comment: Using a goal of appengine:devserver, that doesn't seem to make a difference. I do not see output in the eclipse console, nor are the breakpoints being hit. The devserver does indeed start, and the app functions as expected, but no debugging.

Comment: I think the webapp is running in a new thread that eclipse is not watching/listening.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915341/appengine-maven-plugin-configuration-options-like-jvm-flags) may give you a hint of the problem. The Maven appengine:devserver starts the development server on a separate process. Eclipse however is only aware of the Maven process itself (this is what you see in the debug view). In addition, since the dev server cannot be started with arguments such as a debug port, it probably can never be connected to a debugger.

The question linked suggest that there's an unofficial Maven GAE plugin which takes arguments. There's also a new ticket to enhance the official plugin and a promise by the plugin developper to implement this feature soon.

Comment: is http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8558 what you are referring to?

Comment: The first issue is a more general problem of Eclipse-GAE-Maven integration. The second issue, is more specific but will help towards that goal. I was referring to the second issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'll see what else I can do to make the eclipse integration easier, but there is now an update to the issue filed to the appengine-maven-plugin project : http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=3&can=1 so take a look and see if the support for the jvm arguments can help you out.

Please let me know your experiences, I'm always in favor of things being awesome.

Comment: Got it working! Takes 2 debug configurations in eclipse, one to execute maven goal and one to connect the eclipse debugger, but that is very tolerable.

Comment: I'd love to see some more functionality to improve the code/execute/debug cycle, including incremental builds and/or hot deploys to the dev server.

Comment: Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/list and let me know if we already have an issue.  If not, feel free to create one.  It would be awesome to make this easier.

Comment: hotswap functionality: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=17

Answer (score 1):

## Answer Relevant in 2015

I created a GAE (Java) project in Sep 2015 and the following applies to this and similar projects.

I started by creating my project as on ordinary GAE maven project using the Skeleton archetype by simply following the relevant steps from [Using Apache Maven - Java — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). Followed through from [Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#requirements) through to [Testing your app with the development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#testing_your_app_with_the_development_server).

After that I imported this project into Eclipse JEE (Mars) using "Import an existing Maven project". Started development.

When I needed to debug, I only had to carry out the few steps explained below.

#### Create a debug configuration

Go to **Run -> Debug Configurations**, click on *Remote Java Application* and create a new configuration by clicking on the **New** button (see screenshot, upper left corner above filter text box).

[image: Create a new debug configuration for Remote Java Application]

Fill in the details by choosing your particular project and giving a suitable name to the configuration as shown below (let port be 8000) and click **Apply**:

[image: Settings for the debug configuration]

#### Uncomment some lines in pom.xml

In your project's pom.xml, find the configuration for plugin `appengine-maven-plugin` and uncomment the following lines:

```
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
```

#### Run the `mvn appengine:devserver` command from the command line

As the title says...

#### Attach the debugger from within Eclipse

Click on the little down-triangle next to the button for **Debug** and choose the name of the debug configuration you just set up ("HelloWorldServlet" in my example).